# Let G be a group and a; b ∈ G. Suppose |a| = |b| = |ab| = 2. Then show that ab = ba.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm having trouble understanding this question and help would be appreciated.

If |ab|=2 and |a|=2, |b|=2, wouldn't this imply that |a||b|=|ab|=4?

How would I go about proving that this is Abelian?

I do know that an identity element exists(by assumption, e=1) and that an inverse for A and B exists, which I'm also assuming is 1/|2|.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The inverse of $a$ is **not** $1/|2|=1/2$ which expression has no meaning here.

Comment: The bars $|a|$ do not mean absolute value here, but order: $|a|$ is the minimal integer $n>0$ such that $a^n=e$. So $|a|=2$ just means $a\neq e$ but $a^2=e$. In particular $|a||b|=|ab|=4$ is nonsense here (though it would be true for absolute values).

Answer (score 9):

Write $abab=e$ and multiply both sides by $ba$.

Comment: Note that right and left multiplication give the same solution in this case, but does not in general.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that it looks like you are confusing two similar notations. When talking about the order of an element $a$ in a group, there are a number of ways of writing it, with $|x|$ being pretty common.

At the same time, in the real numbers, we use $|x|$ to denote the absolute value of an element $x$, which satisfies $|xy| = |x||y|$.

However! Just because we are using the same notation doesn't mean that the same properties hold. In particular, it is *not* in general true that in a group $|ab| = |a||b|$. This does happen *some of the time*, but by no means is it generally true. For examples, see the other answers.

In short: one should not be tricked by common notation into believing that properties carry over; make sure you are aware of what context that notation is from, and what properties hold *in that context*.

Answer (score 3):

There are several questions in one question here and I'll try to answer those seperately. First of all on orders of elements: the easiest possible example to se that $|a||b|=|ab|$ does not necessarily hold is in the (additive) group $\mathbb{Z}/(2)\times\mathbb{Z}/(2)$. If $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(0,1)$, both elements have order $2$ and $a+b=(1,1)$ has order $2$ just as well.

For the next question, one has to consider what it means that $|a|=2$. It means that $a^2=1$, i.e. $a^{-1}=a$. It thus follows that $b^{-1}=b$ and $(ab)^{-1}=ab$, while in general $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. (Can you see why?) Combining these facts, we find $ab=(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$.

The main point to remember is that if an element in a group has order $2$, it is its own inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Since $|ab| = 2$, we know that

$$\begin{align}
(ab)(ab) &= e \\
a^{-1}(ab)(ab)b^{-1} &= a^{-1}eb^{-1} \\
ebae &= a^{-1}eb^{-1} \\
ba &= a^{-1}b^{-1} \\
ba &= (aa)a^{-1}b^{-1}(bb) \\
ba &= a(aa^{-1})(b^{-1}b)b \\
ba &= aeeb \\
ba &= ab \\
\end{align}$$

At least that's how I think it goes; I haven't done group theory in 2+ years.

Also, I am new here, so please excuse the way I typed it; I still have to learn how to use the coding.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I've edited your answer to fix the typesetting. Here's a tutorial/reference so you will know how to do it in the future. :-) http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you, Bungo. I'll learn it bit by bit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $|a| = 2$, $a^2 = e$.  Similarly, $|b| = 2 \Rightarrow b^2 = e$ and $|ab| = 2 \Rightarrow (ab)(ab) = e$.

If we left-multiply the equation $$abab = e$$ by $a$ and right-multiply it by $b$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
aababb & = aeb\\
(aa)(ba)(bb) & = ab\\
e(ba)e & = ab\\
ba & = ab
\end{align*}

where we have used the fact that if an element has order $2$, then it is its own inverse.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite oneliner: $ab = a(ab)^2 b = aababb = a^2 ba b^2 = ba$.

(Edit: it's the short form of the answer given by N.F. Taussig.)